# Converting BMP to Grey Scale in Image Module Python

Tags: python, image

I was wondering how I can convert BMPs to a grey scale using Image Module of Python?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Greyscale image mode is [`'L'`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/concepts.htm#mode).

```
>>> import Image
>>> Image.open('input.bmp').convert('L').save('output.bmp')
```